# How to disable login and registration pages?

Tags: redirect, login, user-registration

I use a login/register plugin and display the forms on a custom page. So I try to find a solution to disable, or even better, redirect URL such as **example.com/wp-login.php**, **example.com/register** (which is the Buddypress register page), **example.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword** to **example.com/login-register/**

I've tried this in htaccess but it doesn't worked out.

```
Redirect 301 "https://example.com/register/" "https://example.com/login-register/"
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right answer :

```
Redirect 301 /register /login-register
```

It works without quotation marks.

And no need to use absolute path (the entire address), except if the redirection goes to another domain. If this is your case, do this:

```
Redirect 301 /register https://example.com/login-register
```

Also, I didn't redirect /wp-login as it caused some issues (inability to log in)

FYI : 301 = permanent redirection, 302 = temporary redirection

[**Source**](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)